# Java ConcurrentHashMap iterating via entrySet vs keySet

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, iteration

Many articles compare these approaches and all are in favor of `entrySet` over `keySet`. All of them take into account the speed, but none heap usage.

- https://coderanch.com/t/203203/java/entrySet-keySet-Map
- https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/hashmap/performance-comparison-of-different-ways-to-iterate-over-hashmap/

Recently, I have implemented some code using `ConcurrentHashMap` and the map on average held 200K - 300K items. We iterate through the whole map every 30s.

During the performance test of the software, I found that GC was taking a hit every 30s, causing lots of objects to be allocated (and freed subsequently). Going further into the analysis, I have found that an abnormal amount of `Entry<K, V>` objects were allocated every 30s.

After switching to iterating over `keySet`, no allocation spikes showed.

I know that:

```
for (String key : testMap.keySet()) {
    testMap.get(key);
}
```

raises warning in both any half-decent IDEs and SonarQube. The performance does also vary with the implementation of the map (e.g. in TreeMap). But it sort of does a better job than the `entrySet`.

Some other SO answers also point out that the cost of doing O(1) lookup (and `hashCode`) is far greater than allocating a new `Entry` each and every time

So, what is your take on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "what's your take on this?" You should know that SO isn't a place for asking about opinions already.

Comment: "So, what is your take on this?" Do what works best for you.

Comment: Nothing to do with opinion, in fact. I meant for someone to suggest to me if they tried something similar as I did and ended up shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: I am honestly surprised that any allocation ends up needing to happen there: it depends on what you're doing in the loop, but you are perhaps unintentionally confounding the escape analysis the JVM uses to avoid unnecessary allocations of short-lived objects.

Comment: Which JDK did you test? A quick glance at `HashMap` JDK18 code suggests that `entrySet().iterator()` passes on the tables own `Map.Entry` values not a new instances.

Comment: @DuncG Have to correct myself - this was `ConcurrentHashMap`, not `HashMap`. On each `next()` it executes `return new MapEntry<K,V>(k, v, map);`. And it was JDK11.

Comment: Not an answer as I'm very interested in any measurements, please do some :). I'd also like to throw in `map.forEach(...)` which is both convenient and should not be thrashing the GC. The problem with `keySet()`+`map.get()` on a concurrent map, is, obviously, that the entry might be gone by the time you get it, so you need to carefully check for nulls etc.

Comment: Back then, I captured profiler screenshots before/after :) https://imgur.com/a/eRdp31z

Comment: @JovanPerovic That explains it, yes the entrySet iteration (including JDK18) does indeed have side effect of generating one new `MapEntry` per key.

Comment: *We iterate through the whole map every 30s.* Why?

Comment: @g00se The map contains all metrics to be retrieved by Prometheus, which scapes the endpoint every 30s. And before you ask - yes, that is an insane amount of metrics, unsuitable for Prometheus